# $y(x) =\int_x^ay(z) \,\mathrm dz$ where $a$ is constant

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$\displaystyle\\y(x) =\int\limits_x^ay(z) \,\mathrm  dz$ where $a$ is a constant

I've tried solving like this. First we can set

$y(x) = Y(a) - Y(x)$ where $Y$ is the primitive of $y$

Then differentiating by $x$ gives

$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = \frac{dY(a)}{dx} - \frac{dY(x)}{dx}$

The first term on the right hand side does not depend on x and therefore is zero. The second term is $y$ integrated with respect to $x$ and then differentiated with respect $x$ which cancels out and just leaves $y$. Overall we get:

$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = -y(x)$

which we solve to get

$y(x) = Ae^x$ where $A$ is a constant

Now I think this is right for when $a$ is infinity but for any other constant I think this is wrong as y(x) must depend on $a$. Can someone please show me where I have gone wrong and the correct way of solving this.

Comment: If you plug in the solution you found, it does not solve the differential equation.

Comment: Please don’t use `\limits` or displaystyle in the title; it puts extra space which messes up lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution should be:
$$y(x) = Ae^{-x},$$
as you can check by differentiating.

Now plugging back in to the integral equation, we get:
$$Ae^{-x} = \int_x^a Ae^{-t} dt = -A(e^{-a} - e^{-x})$$
Thus:
$Ae^{-a} = 0$, hence $A = 0$. Thus the only solution is $y(x) =0$. Except in the case where $a = \infty$, in which case these manipulations aren't valid, but you can check in that case that $a = \infty$, that $Ae^{-x}$ works for any $A$.

Answer (score 0):

**The Mistake**: You missed the negative sign in front of $y(x)$ while integrating!

***Another Approach***: You can also differentiate  $y(x)=\int_x^ay(z)dz$ under the integral sign using [*Newton-Leibniz Formula*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html)
as follows:

$$\frac d{dx}y(x)=\frac d{dx}\int_x^ay(z)dz$$
$$y'(x)=\frac d{dx}(a).y(a)-\frac d{dx}(x).y(x)$$
$\therefore$ 
$$y'(x)=-y(x)$$
Now, separating like terms and integrating
$$-\int\frac {dy(x)}{y(x)}=\int dx \implies ln(y(x))+ln(A')=-x $$ 
$$y(x)=A.e^{-x}$$ where $A$ is a Constant ($A=\frac1{A'})$.